# I can't get my case statement in my where clause to work with a parameter

Tags: sql-server, case, ssms, where-clause

I'm making a report that allows me to see information depending on if I have paid for Freight or not.

```sql
SELECT...
FROM...
WHERE CASE 
      WHEN @Billed = 1 THEN Freight > 0
      WHEN @Billed = 0 THEN Freight = 0
      ELSE Freight >= 0 END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The predicate of a `CASE` expression (i.e. what follows `THEN` or `ELSE`) has to be a literal value, and cannot be another logical expression.  You may rephrase your `CASE` logic as follows:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE
    (@Billed = 1 AND Freight > 0) OR
    (@Billed = 0 AND Freight = 0) OR
    Freight >= 0;
```